# Python RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

It is a very common issue, but I cannot actually find a proper answer to it. I have the following code to connect to a server through a websocket and I want to keep it alive and keep listening to messages it sends like below:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
            
async def listen_for_message(websocket):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print(message)

async def connect_to_dealer():
    websocket = await websockets.connect(websocketadress)

    hello_message = await websocket.recv()
    print(hello_message)

async def my_app():
    websocket = await connect_to_dealer()
    asyncio.ensure_future(listen_for_message(websocket))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(my_app())
    loop.run_forever()
```

And it raises the error:

```
  File "\untitled0.py", line 71, in <module>
    loop.run_forever()
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 525, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running') 
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

And without the

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

I get:

```
  File "\untitled0.py", line 70, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(my_app()) 
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 525, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

I still do not understand why it does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loop.run_until_complete()` already runs your loop 'forever'.

Instead of firing of your `listen_for_message()` awaitable as a task, just await on it. That then runs forever, because `listen_for_message()` itself never returns:

```
async def my_app():
    websocket = await connect_to_dealer()
    await listen_for_message(websocket)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(my_app())
```

Note that your `connect_to_dealer()` function **doesn't return the websocket**; that's probably an oversight you want to correct:

```
async def connect_to_dealer():
    return await websockets.connect(websocketadress)
```

I removed the `hello_message = await websocket.recv()` / `print(hello_message)` lines there because `listen_for_message()` will already receive messages and print them.